# BIP Excel Bursting issues

Tags: bi-publisher

I have customized a seeded 'Payables Payment Register' report/data model by utilizing 'Customize' option from /xmlpserver link in our environment. I changed the report so that is it not controlled via external application (ESS Job) so that I could schedule it directly in BI Publisher and Burst excel file to an email address.

The issue I am seeing is that when the report runs and outputs using the Bursting definition, it is excluding some of the fields on each sheet of the Excel file. If I run the report without the Bursting definition selected then I am seeing all the fields populated on each sheet in the Excel output, as I would expect to see. Output examples are below, with and without Bursting:

**Sheet1 (With Bursting Query enabled)** - Notice the report parameter values are missing here:

[image]

**Sheet2 (With Bursting Query enabled):** again notice the Bank information below is missing:

[image]

**Sheet1 (Without Bursting output enabled)** - Notice the Report Parameters are populated (as I would expect):

[image]

**Sheet2 (Without Bursting output enabled)** - Notice the Bank information is populated (as I would expect):

[image]

**Bursting Query:**

```
select 
'H' as "KEY",
'Payables_Payment_Register' TEMPLATE,
'en-US' LOCALE,
'xlsx' OUTPUT_FORMAT,
'EMAIL' DEL_CHANNEL,
'Payables_Payment_Register_' || TRUNC(SYSDATE) OUTPUT_NAME,
EMAIL.email_address PARAMETER1,
'bipublisher-report@oracle.com' PARAMETER3,
'Payables_Payment_Register_' || TRUNC(SYSDATE) PARAMETER4,
'Please find attached the Payables Payment Register for the current week for our Enterprise.' PARAMETER5,
'true' PARAMETER6,
'no-reply@oracle.com' PARAMETER7
  ,NULL  "PARAMETER8" -- not used
  ,NULL  "PARAMETER9" --not used
  ,NULL  "PARAMETER10" -- not used
from PER_PERSON_NAMES_F NAME, PER_EMAIL_ADDRESSES EMAIL
WHERE EMAIL.Person_id = NAME.Person_id
AND NAME.FULL_NAME IN ('Smith, John')
```

**Example code in report template:**
[image]

I have also tried this with PDF output in both the Bursting query and the default output format, and the same issue is occuring, so I am really leaning toward something in the bursting that is causing this.

I would like to understand why this is happening and how to fix this so that both the Report Parameters and Bank information display when the report is output via the Bursting definition.

Please let me know if you need any other information. I can provide the report template also if necessary. Thank you in advance!